# request.getParameter without checking the checkbox in UI ... Servlets (J2EE)

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets

I have seen so many articles but never got this point. Can you explain why ?

Here is the code I do have:

HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="mailing" /> Would you like to join our mailing list ?
```

SERVLET:

```
request.getParameter("mailing").equals("on") ? true : false; // Error if I have NOT checked the checkbox.

"on".equals(request.getParameter("mailing")) ? true : false; // No Error - Works as Expected.
```

What is the difference between these two ?

Comment: `foo ? true : false` is completely superfluous . Just use `foo`

Comment: Because constant value should always come first in comparison.

Comment: @Arin err, no. That is factually incorrect, and most of the time, bad practice.

Comment: @JB Nizet. got ur point. thanks for correcting me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a checkbox is unchecked, the corresponding parameter is not sent at all by the browser when submitting the form.

So `request.getParameter("mailing")` returns null. Calling `equals("on")` on null throws a NullPointerException.

On the other hand, `"on".equals(null)` doesn't cause any exception to be thrown, because a correct `equals()` method always returns false when the argument is null.

Note that

```
boolean b = "on".equals(request.getParameter("mailing")) ? true : false;
```

is bad practice, and shows a lack of understanding. It should simply be written as

```
boolean b = "on".equals(request.getParameter("mailing"));
```